# Determining if user has denied CoreLocation permission

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-location

Is it possible to determine programmatically that a user has denied permission to use their location?

Secondly, if a user has denied permission, is it possible to re-prompt the user?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can determine your authorization status using the `authorizationStatus` class method on `CLLocationManager`. This returns a `CLAuthorizationStatus` which is defined as:

```
typedef enum {
   kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined = 0,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized
} CLAuthorizationStatus;
```

The system will prompt the user to authorize your application if the authorization status is undetermined when you attempt to start the location manager.

Additionally, you can check the `locationServicesEnabled` class method to determine if location is enabled system wide.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally - If locationServicesEnabled returns NO and you attempt to start location services anyway, the system will prompt the user to confirm whether location services should be reenabled.