# How to detect if a user says no to use my default location?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-location

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determining if user has denied CoreLocation permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661653/determining-if-user-has-denied-corelocation-permission)

How would I go about detecting if a user says no to "use my default location" in an iOS app?

I would like to present them with a different view controller depending on their choice.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that, you need to implement below delegate method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    if([error code]== kCLErrorDenied)
        self.locationDenied = YES;

        switch ([error code]) {
        // "Don't Allow" on two successive app launches is the same as saying "never allow". The user
        // can reset this for all apps by going to Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location Warnings.
        case kCLErrorDenied:
            [appDelegate showAllowGPSLocationView];
        default:
            break;
    }

    self.locationDefined = NO;
}
```

You can create method "showAllowGPSLocationView" in AppDelegate. And show view to user that, you need to access GPS location.

Hope it will resolve your issue.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {

    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        // denied
    }
    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        // allowed
    }
}
```

Implement `CLLocationManagerDelegate` delegate
For detailed explanation refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13910748/how-to-detect-user-selects-dont-allow-for-mkmapview-for-iphone).Worked for me.Hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below:

```
 #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED > __IPHONE_4_2
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] && ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized))  
 #else 
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])    
 #endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a function for that that solves the problem in two ways: first checks if location services are enabled (first location setting on device) and second checks if user authorized your app.

```
- (bool)locationAvailable
{
    if (!([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) || ( [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied))
        return FALSE;
    else
        return TRUE;
}
```